# How can I use `TAB` with `M-x` to cycle through commands matching minibuffer input

Tags: completion, minibuffer, cycling

I am finding completion in Emacs system to work similarly to `bash` completion, in the sense that upon pressing `TAB`, it presents the user with a list of possible options.

However, I am looking for something more similar to `zsh`, where pressing `TAB` completes my input to the nearest match, and pressing `TAB` again subsequently cycles through remaining matches. Does something like this exist in Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such `TAB` completion is available in Emacs, and not just for `M-x` (completing command names).

1. With vanilla Emacs, that is, without any additional library, you can have `TAB` cycle among completions by customizing user option `completion-cycle-threshold` to a number or the value `t`.  If a number `N` then `TAB` cycles only when there are fewer than `N` completions of your input.  If `t` then `TAB` always cycles, no matter how many completions there are.

   See the Emacs manual, node [Completion Options](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Completion-Options.html), for more info.  (You can get to this doc in Emacs itself using `C-h r g completion options`.)
2. In addition, there are several 3rd-party libraries that offer very useful `TAB` completion, including these:

   - [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles)
   - [Ivy](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper)
   - [Helm](https://emacs-helm.github.io/helm/)
   - [Consult](https://github.com/plexus/consult)